# Jade Syntax Error not catching

Tags: express, pug

Recently I was working on a website to add google maps using `expressJS` and `jade`.
I had a 'spelling' error in `jade` that did not allow google maps to load correctly (no display).

No error was thrown anywhere and it took a lot of time to figure out that the cause was a missing letter 's' that prevented the map from rendering.

Is there a way to catch said errors in `jade`?
Do I have to modify `express`?

Below are the `jade` files that I was using.

**layout.jade**

```
!!! 5
html(lang='en')
  include includes/head
  body
    .wrapper
      include includes/header
      block content
      include includes/footer
```

**includes/head.jade**

```
head
  meta(charset='UTF-8')
  title= title
  block stylesheets
    link(href='/site.css', rel='stylesheet', )
  block scripts
```

**Gmap.jade**

```
extends ../layout

append stylesheets
  style
    #Gmap{
      height: 400px;
      width: 760px;
    }
    etc...

append scripts
  script(src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false')
  etc ...
```

In the `includes/head.jade` there is a `block stylesheets`.
In the `Gmap.jade` the `append stylesheets` is called.
`stylesheets` was misspelled as `stylesheet` and it took me a long time to find this.
No errors were thrown, the webpage rendered 'ok' without the google map.

Can `jade`/`express` be customized to throw an error when there is a mismatch?
(aside from being more careful in writing things out).

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this if you ever figured it out.

Comment: I have not figured it out.  I've just been extra careful.  I think I'll just send an issue to https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues and post an answer if they respond.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused, you're saying no error at all was thrown?  So the screen was completely blank?

Are you using `express.errorHandler()` somewhere in your server code?  You can set error message something like this.

```
app.use( express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true , showStack: true }) ))
```

That may fix the issue of you having no error messages. If you would like more information on the Express.js error handler, you can check out [this page](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/errorHandler.html).  Express is just a wrapper around Connect.js; this is the underlying code.

Comment: As I state above everything came out 'ok' except the google map.  No errors were thrown.  And I did use `app.use( ...`